# Connecting to MySql Database using Java

Tags: java, mysql, database, connection, database-connection

So I've been teaching myselft mysql and am trying to integrate it into my Java code. I've looked at some past code snippets and tutorials and I can't seem to figure out why my code is incorrect. (removed password for obvious reasons)

Here's what I'm using to connect

```
  public static void connectionToMySql(){
    String host = "mysql9.000webhost.com";
    String username = "a9808220_pin";
    String pass = "";
    try{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(host,username,pass);
      /*insert code*/
        connection.close();
        System.out.println("It worked :)");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Something went wrong :(");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I get an exception that there's no suitable driver. I'm not sure why because I have the jar downloaded and pathed correctly

Comment: What is the exact type of the Exception you get? And how you included the MySQL jar in your classpath?

Comment: "java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for mysql9.000webhost.com" I downloaded the jar and set my project structure so that it used it. Before I had it, it said it couldn't find the driver class. But after I downloaded the jar, it now gets this exception.

Comment: In row 6 you just instantiating the MySQL driver but doing nothing with it, not even assigning it to a variable. What if you register the created Driver object instance with DriverManager.registerDriver()?

Comment: Like this? " Driver driver = (Driver) Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
            DriverManager.registerDriver(driver);" still get the same thing

Comment: I would be really surprised if that's the problem because that's how I've seen it done in many tutorials and snippets

Comment: I just realized that the first argument of `DriverManager.getConnection` should be a `url` not a host. See it [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html#getConnection(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)).

Comment: So what should I use instead? I don't understand. I'm using 000webhost to host it under the domain pinnacleenergy.comxa.com. It displays this on the control panel "Important: MySQL Host for any database in this account is mysql9.000webhost.com , do not use localhost!" which is why im using that

Comment: It should be like this: `String host = "jdbc:mysql://mysql9.000webhost.com:3306/yourDatabaseName`.

Comment: Ah thanks, I get by that exception now. But my code timesout and I don't understand why since I know the database is up

Comment: Do you try to connect to this server through internet or some local network? Because the host `mysql9.000webhost.com` resolves to `10.1.1.109` which isn't a public internet ip address.

Comment: Here's what I'm getting now              java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
 at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. This is one of my first time using databases sorry for my ignorance. I got a domain from 000webhost, and made a database for it. From there I added a table to the database. And now I'm trying to practice inserting things into the table

Comment: Ugh I just opened phpmyadmin and it says my database is on the local host :/ So I guess that explains why it isn't working. Guess I need to figure out how to put it on the server??

Comment: You are a bit confused, aren't you? I think first you have to clean up the all the facts about the resources you try to use, understand how you connect to a remote server, how you can reach your own server and if all that's clear than try to connect to it from Java.

Answer (score 0):

String host should be like

```
String host = "jdbc:mysql:ip:port"//ip or hostname
```

example code that works for me...

```
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:1433;"
                 +"databaseName=test;"
                 +"user=sa;"
                 +"password=xxxxx;");
         System.out.println("connected");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your connection should be a JDBC URL in the form

```
String url = "jdbc:mysql://mysql9.000webhost.com:3306/";
```

Now in order for this to work you should:

1) Verify that mySQL is running on the host mysql9.000webhost.com

2) Verify that the port is the default port ie 3306, if not change the code above to use the right port

Comment: Thanks, I got past that exception. But for some reason now I timeout trying to connect and I'm unsure why it can't connect successfully

Comment: You need debug the connectivity. It may be any number of things: server is unreachable, its not running on the default port, etc..